# Android: play video 3 seconds after click

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, video

I have a web application with a video player. When the user presses a button, the video starts playing. Now, I added an animation that starts when the button is clicked, en when it finishes, the video should start playing. The animation is based on setInterval (to be more precise, the HTML5 variant, requestInterval).

This works perfectly, but only on a Mac/PC, because there are restrictions for video playback on Android. When you want a video to actually start playing programmatically, the function that calls the play() function of the video element needs to be directly triggered by a user action (e.g. click on a button).

Before the animation, this was indeed the case, and everything worked as intended. I need the video to play only after the animation is finished, because there is considerable lag on the animation if the video starts playing when the animation starts.

Any ideas or workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onclick="setInterval(function(){alert('Start the video now!')},3000);">Try it</button>
```

Or

```
var timerOut=setInterval(function(){startTimer()},3000);

function startTimer()
{
  //Start video here
    clearInterval(timerOut);
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I had to mention I am using JavaScript (not a native Android Java app, but a web app)

Answer (score 0):

I see that you use jquery (from the tags).
If the animation is implemented with the .animate() function you could use the callback:

```
$( "#btn" ).click(function() {
   $( "#animate" ).animate({ //opts go here }, 5000, function() {
     // Animation complete.
   });
});
```

If you use the transition css3 property you could use the transitionend event handler:

```
$('#animate').off('transitionend').on('transitionend', function() {
    // Animation complete.
});
```

EDIT:

I guess you're using the drawImage() function which is synchronous, but the image loading is not.

Try to add an onload event handler on the image(s), something like this:

```
   var img = new Image();
   img.src = "http://image.ext";                
   img.onload = function(){
      // drawImage goes here
   }
```

If you have multiple images you could implement something like this:

```
var $imgs = ... // this will store all img objects
var imgLength = $imgs.length;
var i = 0;
$imgs.each(function() {
   i += 1;
   $(this).onload = function() {
      if(i === imgLength) //drawImage
   }
});
```

Comment: I'm drawing images on a canvas at 20 FPS, which leaves only the setInterval option open (I guess?)

Answer (score 0):

For starting an Action after an Animation in Android, it´s good to use the AnimationListener. There is a method inside:

```
       @Override
   public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {


     //do Your stuff here
 }
```

Look to the devoloper resources:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html

and here an example:

http://android-er.blogspot.de/2011/09/handle-animation-event.html